# Sproutcore Datasource: How should a created record be saved in the datasource?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, record, sproutcore

After creating and commiting the records to `store`, how do we "save" it so as to so that the updated changes in the database is not lost on refreshing the browser? Currently, this is what is being done:

```
toBeAdded = Tree.store.createRecord(Tree.Note, 

                    {
                    guid: 324,
                    name: this.get('newItem'),
                    categoryId: categoryId,
                    content: "This is a newly added item"
                        }
                    );
          Tree.store.commitRecords();
```

I'm not familiar with the technical details of Sproutcore as I'm quite new to this. Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the method commitRecords on your SC.Store instance (Tree.store), the data should be commit to your server. 
For that, you have to implemente the method createRecords in your [SC.DataSource](http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.DataSource.html) instance.

Here is a tutorial about it: http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/12413058/Todos%2007-Hooking%20Up%20to%20the%20Backend